# Find $[\Bbb Z_{40} : \langle[12], [20]\rangle]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find $[\Bbb Z_{40} : \langle[12], [20]\rangle]$

So I believe that the question is talking about the smallest subgroup which contains $12, 20$ which I believe is $\langle 4 \rangle$

What next?

Comment: This question is equivalent to finding the number of cosets of $\langle 4\rangle$ there are in $\Bbb Z_{40}$.

Comment: @Shaun, I  believe I need to divide the order of the whole group (40) by the order ofthe subgroup (10), which gives 4. Is this the correct rule?

Comment: Almost, @cele; but $40/10=4$.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote & accept my answer :)

Comment: @Shaun yes sorry. That's what I meant. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, @cele.

Comment: of course. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, we have $$\lvert G\rvert=[G:H]\lvert H\rvert.$$